# Calling a module with different Array element in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have input like that

```
a1 = 4'b 1001;
a2 = 4'b 1000;
a3 = 4'b 1111;
```

say I have a module fulladder that takes three inputs . 
I need to call this module with all LSB of input that is  like that

```
fulladder fa (a1[3] , a2[3] , a2[4] )  

    module full adder (a,b,c, carry , sum);
    body -----
    endmodule
```

it works fine with me !!

but but if the fulladder takes input value as array 
like bellow then how I can call the module;

```
module fulladder2 (a , sum, carry)
 input [2:0] a;
 output sum;
 output carry; 
 body-----
endmoduole
```

example 
`fulladder2 f2 (3'b.a(a1[3]a2[3]a2[4])` ?? it shows error can not declare ASCII in binary

or `fulladder2 f2 (.a(a1[3],a2[3],a2[4])` ?? it also show error .

I can not convert the module fulladder2 like fulladder .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the concatenation operator {...}.

```
fulladder2 f2( {a1[3],a2[3],a3[3]}, ...
better:
fulladder2 f2 (
      .a     ( {a1[3],a2[3],a3[3]} ),
      .sum   (sum),
      .carry (carry)
      );
```

Also I noticed two different definitions where you have swapped the carry and sum.

```
module full adder (a,b,c, carry , sum);
and:
module fulladder2 (a , sum, carry)
```

That is not a problem if you use the .name(...) port assignment but it is a potential danger if you don't.

As to your nomenclature: what you use is called a 'vector' not an 'array'. In Verilog a one dimensional entity is called a vector. An array is normally two dimensional.  A single bit is a wire or reg.